# File Search and Matching

Tags: php, pdf

I create PDF files with PHP script and now I want to search folder by file name. There are ONLY PDF files in the folder and look like this:

Order Number + Customer Name + Amount

```
200_Anton_60.pdf
201_Peter_40.pdf
202_Melanie_60.pdf
```

Filename in details:

```
(Integer, unique and autoincrement) _ (string variable) _ (integer variable).pdf
```

Now I want before saving the PDF file Check:
Search Existing files in the folder, If order number and customer name match, ONLY amount is different, move PDF file into subfolders.

I hope you can help me!

Comment: I would sugest writing code to do it. Have you tried or do you want us to do it for you ?

Comment: I have already written. Unfortunately does not work.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17518522/search-pdf-file-names-and-compare

Comment: So this question is a duplicate of your earlier question?

Comment: Yes, I thought the other script is complicated.

Comment: I think you should have one subfolder with order number and customer name,and all files should be saved in that folder.

Comment: That wasn't the problem with your question I think. The problem is that you don't explain what isn't working... You can close this one and edit the previous one

Comment: are you sure? I can not check in folder existing file name? If order number and customer name matches ONLY amount is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
$dir = "your_dir";

$order_no = 300;
$cust_name = "ABC";
$amount = 200;

foreach(glob($dir . '/*.pdf') as $file) 
{ 
    $dot = strrpos($file, '.');
    $file_amt = substr($file, 0, $dot);
    $file_amt = substr($file_amt, strrpos($file_amt, '/') + 1);
    $us = strrpos($file, '_');
    $file = substr($file, 0, $us);
    $file = substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);
    if($file == $order_no."_".$cust_name)
    { 
        if($file_amt == $order_no."_".$cust_name."_".$amount)
        {
            //do nothing
        }
        else
        {
            //if order no. and name matches
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //save directly
    }
}
```

Comment: Only for understanding. $amount variable for what you've created? Is not used in your script. Can I instead of "//moving into subfolders" and "//save directly" there will generate variable and access it outside the script?

Comment: @rafig: for using outside you have to declare them before `foreach` loop and then assign value to them in conditions.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. After the change amount, for the same customer name and order number, the new PDF file will be saved in the same folder instead of / subfolder / :- (

Comment: $PDFdir = $path."files/";       
$order_no = 10503;
$cust_name = David;
$amount = 60; // before 50. file with the name 10503_David_50.pdf exists.
$foundDiffAmount = false;
foreach(glob($PDFdir.'*.pdf') as $file) { 
$us = strrpos($file, '_');
$file = substr($file, 0, $us);
if($file == $order_no."_".$cust_name) { 
$foundDiffAmount = true;                   
} 
} 

if ($foundStorno == true) {

//moving into subfolders

}

Comment: @rafig: from where `$foundStorno` is set? I think there shuold be `$foundDiffAmount`.

Comment: I have renamed him only here, in the original code both is the same. 

$foundDiffAmount = false; and $foundDiffAmount = true;

Comment: @rafig: ok, but in last if condition `if($foundStorno == true)` , is there `$foundStorno` or it should be `$foundDiffAmount`.

Comment: if ($foundDiffAmount = true) { //moving into subfolders }

Comment: My idea would be to first search for order number and customer name in a file, like this:

$findMatchOrder = strpos($allFiles, $OrderAndCustomerNumber);

Then I would check if in this file existing amount with the current amount match, if not move the current file in the subfolder.

unfortunately I'm not good in PHP, so I hope for your help. :-)

Comment: @rafig: Please check the updated code, I added one line that remove directory name from `$file`. And you put `$us = strrpos($file, '');` instead of `$us = strrpos($file, '_');`, so take care about that thing. And second thing is please be careful at `glob()` that there will be no two slash `/` when you concat it to the `/*.pdf`.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

PHP 5.3, I think because glob is within a foreach.

Comment: @rafig: what you pass in `$dir`?

Comment: Files will be created anyway, you're right. I have included the:
ini_set ('display_errors', 0);

It is very frustrating, it still does not work move the files to the subfolder. :-)


My Current Code:

$dir = "http://mydomain.com/export/pdf/2013/Jul/";
  
  // Check Storno //
  $order_no = 10503;
  $cust_name = David;  
  $foundDiffAmount = false;

  foreach (glob($dir.'*.pdf') as $file) {
   $us = strrpos($file, '_');
   $file = substr($file, 0, $us);
   $file = substr($file, strrpos($file, '/') + 1);
   if($file == $order_no.$cust_name) { 
     $foundDiffAmount = true;}  }

Comment: Yes, Yes, Yes! :-) Thank you very much man.

No contact info in your web site for conversation? :-)

Comment: hi,
Now I have the problem that he also moves duplicates to the subfolders and ignore my previous code. :-(

I would like if all three parameters match, not to save him. Example

10503_David_60.pdf (PDF file exists in the folder) => make nothing.
10503_Davi_15.pdf => save in subfolders.

Comment: Could you comment your code so I know what you want to do. :-). I was happy at first, but then saw that the code also moves the existing PDF documents (duplicates) in the subfolder. I think we have problem understanding. :-)

Here is my modified code, see new If () to you. I had, after order number and customer name matches the check amount.

if($file == $order_no."_".$cust_name && strpos($us, $amount) === false) {//moving into subfolders}

Comment: @rafig: so now you want to "do nothing" with the files that exactly match [including amount] with your previous files. If I understood right? And you put condition `strpos($us, $amount)` it never gonna be true, because `$us` does not contain amount so condition will false always.

Comment: good morning! :-) exactly looking PDF file and see if order number and customer name matches ONLY amount is another move that file, otherwise do nothing. I know strpos does not work.

Comment: @rafig: I've updated my code to identify the order no., name and amount matches. If it is that you need?

Comment: this option possible?: //if order no. and name matches only amount is another. that's what I need.

Comment: @rafig: that is already in first `if` condition. Can you post your whole code at http://pastebin.com/ so that I can find out what's going wrong.

Comment: @rafig: can you try this http://pastebin.com/a0R7gFWK and tell me what is printed.

Comment: did you edit the code? (I've seen no change.) It still works not. :-(

Comment: @rafig: I've put two echo in foreach loop, did they print anything?

Comment: @rafig: put `echo "directory : "$PDFdir;` and tell me the output.

Comment: 2013/Jul/09/45_Nachname_120.pdf
45_Nachname
2013/Jul/09/46_Nachname_158.pdf
46_Nachname
2013/Jul/09/47_Nachname_502.pdf
47_Nachname
2013/Jul/09/47_Nachname_509.pdf
47_Nachname
2013/Jul/09/48_Nachname_4.pdf
48_Nachname
2013/Jul/09/51_Doe_886.pdf
51_Doe

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood you. Here is the result.

Comment: directory : /server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09//server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09/45_Nachname_120.pdf

Comment: now enter this input `$order_no = 45;` `$cust_name = "Nachname";` `$amount = 200;` and put `echo "true";` in if and put `echo "false";` in else and give me the printed output

Comment: directory : /server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09//server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09/45_Nachname_120.pdf
45_Nachname
true/server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09/46_Nachname_158.pdf
46_Nachname
false/server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09/47_Nachname_502.pdf
47_Nachname

Comment: false/server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09/47_Nachname_509.pdf
47_Nachname
false/server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09/48_Nachname_4.pdf
48_Nachname
false/server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09/48_Nachname_43.pdf
48_Nachname
false/server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09/48_Nachname_48.pdf
48_Nachname
false/server/pdf/modules/PDF-Pro/quixplorer/pdf/2013/Jul/09/51_Doe_886.pdf
51_Doe
false

Comment: @rafig: in second last comment it prints true that means `if($pathPDF == $OrderNumber."_".$CustomerName)` condition it satisfy, so make `$foundDiffAmount = true;` to `$foundDiffAmount = "true";` and at the time of checking use as `if($foundDiffAmount == "true")`

Comment: If he finds the same file, it moves the in the subfolders.
Otherwise works correctly. Now I just have to ask if (file_exists ())?

Comment: @rafig: it moves to the subfolder, then what else you need? you can not use `file_exists()` because is only works when complete filename matches.

Comment: If, order number and customer name match but the amount is different, move this file into the subfolder.

Comment: If, order number, customer name and amount match, do nothing or replace file, etc. But do not move.

Comment: @rafig: oh man, got your point. check new edit and tell me if there is any problem.

Comment: no, does not work! :-( 

Here: http://pdf.oxid-design.com/modules/PDF-Pro//quixplorer/src/index.php

Comment: It just does not work. Now he does not move file even after I changed amount. I think first if () should look something like this:

if ($file_amt == $order_no."_".$cust_name."_" && $file_amt_amount != $amount)
{ //move file to /subfolder
}

Comment: @rafig: I tried this code on 2-3 different cases, it works fine. I think you should debug your code from first so that the bug can be identify.

Comment: but for the second if () query I need check again otherwise files will not be moved.

//if order no. and name matches

Comment: I finally found the correct solution to my problem. I thank you for your effort!